# React native after window restart gives error module.js:549

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, adb

i have a react project . just started with react at the moment. there are a lot of configurations and steps that i have to perform to setup react development server and while i have been working before restarting my machine app was working fine. but after restart node start struct at start packaging and giving me the following error.

[image: Screen-shot]

Error :

```
 D:\node\app>node start
module.js:549
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'app'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

i have no clue what goes wrong . did anyone faced same problem . note that i have no space in my project's parent folder name. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think i have figured it out . i have cmd with opened as administrative . so it might have something or some type of problem with node after running as `ctrl + window` key and typing cmd , then navigate to my folder as " `cd /d D:\node\app\` " and then run `node start` fixed the problem . hoped this might help someone else 
screen shot 
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHH34.png)